# Airflow Remote PythonOperator

Tags: python, airflow

I have a python script in my locale file and I don't want to SCP it to the remote machine and run with SSHOperator remotely triggered by airflow. How can I run a locale .py file in a remote machine and get results?

I need SSHOperator with python_callable, not bash_command.

Can anyone show me a remote custom operator sample like SSHPYTHONOperator ?

I solve problem following:

```
gettime="""
import os
import datetime

def gettimes():
   print(True)

gettimes()
"""

remote_python_get_delta_times=SSHOperator(task_id= "get_delta_times",do_xcom_push=True,
command="MYVAR=`python -c" + ' "%s"`;echo $MYVAR' % gettime ,dag=dag,ssh_hook=remote)
```

Comment: Create a python file after ssh and running could be a workaround!

Answer (score 1):

I see an SSH operator in the Airflow docs: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.13/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/ssh_operator/index.html

If that doesn't work out for you then, you'll have to create a custom Operator using an SSH library like [Paramiko](https://pypi.org/project/paramiko/)
and then use it to pull code from either Github/S3 or SCP your file to the server and then execute it there.

You would need to make sure all your dependencies are also installed on the remote server.